# Android Program to move an image left to right and repeat it again

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android app in which an image will move from left to right and then it will start again moving left to right after sometime. Also image should move based on some distance stored in a CSV file. I have used animation but the image is moving from left to right and then stops at the right end. It should move until it get vanished.

Comment: I am using  TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-1500.0f, 1500.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);...the image is moving from left to right accordingly..But I want the image to be moved based on some distance(like 1 CM, 2 CM etc.) which will be in a CSV file stored in the mobile...

Comment: Here is some part of my code..                                                               final ImageView i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i1);
   i1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                 TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-1500.0f, 1500.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       animation.setDuration(5000);
      
       animation.setRepeatMode(2);
       animation.setFillAfter(true);
       i1.startAnimation(animation);

Comment: @Hints edit ur ques with the code, not in the comments

Answer (score 0):

try the api of Android Animation [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE)

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```